# Fields in the XAML editor Property window becoming un-responsive

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Edit: I see "Silverlight -" is in front of my question, which I realize may have something to do with the alphabetical order of my tabs... really Visual Studio 2013 should be in front, anyone know if that can be changed?

I've been using the newer Visual Studio 2013 for about a week now, and I've found some quirks with it. The one that seems to happen the most is when I'm in the XAML editor working on something, suddenly if I go over to the property window I can't enter anything. I'm not running/debugging. I can type stuff in the regular XAML code editor window.

Even stranger, one of the times, I could get the cursors to appear in the fields. I typed a bunch of junk and just one character from what I types appeared. Another time I couldn't enter values into the properties, but I could double click on an event in the events window and create a new event handler. Just a minute ago I had the opposite, where I couldn't double click in the events window.

I think VS 2013 introduced async handling of more things, could it be related to that? Or perhaps because I'm using Silverlight? Right now my only workaround is to restart VS, does anyone have any knowledge about this? Anyone else experienced this?

I'm going to submit a bug report, but it would be a while before there's a patch, so I'm wondering if maybe someone understand the problem better and has a workaround? Or maybe just confirm that this exists and that I'm not crazy/my computer's haunted.

Edit:
I should mention another weird thing that happened two nights ago. I thought it was some how my doing, but I never figured out how I could have managed it without noticing. I was working on a piece of code, went to run after changing a few lines, and suddenly I had a ton of compiler errors. I go over to a user control I haven't touched in hours and suddenly the main LayoutRoot grid is completely empty. Luckily I'd committed to source control, but still...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an easy way to deal with this problem. It happens a lot after debugging so what I did was I created a batch file on my desktop containing this line `taskkill /f /im XDesProc.exe` and I run it every time the properties start misbehaving. Its the quickest way to reload the designer's functionality. I submitted this bug to microsoft they claim it will be included in the next update.

Comment: Is this only a problem that exists with Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Me and another guy are developing a silverlight app and having the same exact problem. I accidentally found where the bug lies and how to mess with it to allow you to type "very briefly". Apparently this has something to do with tooltips. If you hover over anything in the property window when this bug is happening and allow a tooltip to popup while your cursor is blinking in a field, for the duration that the tooltip is up you can resume typing normal. As soon as the tooltip times out and disappears you can't type. So the only way you can edit or search properties is while a mouse tooltip is floating active. Very unusual. Can't seem to find any kind of tooltip settings in the program and the situation is very hard to find on google because search results assume your talking about programming tooltips. As far as I know we have had this issue since before release candidate. We are currently on official update 1 with the same problem persisting.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, instead of restarting visual studio just unload the solutions your working on and reload them and that will fix the issue without a full restart.

Comment: I wonder if the programmers gave less love to the Silverlight designer, not that I can blame them. Just wanted to pop in and say I used your tooltip workaround this morning. Thanks for that.